# Find all positive integers $n$, such that $(\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor^{2} +2) | (n^2 + 1) $

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I tried to look at the cases when $n$ is a perfect square. Then $\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor^{2} +2= n+2$, $ n^2 + 1 =(n-2)(n+2) + 5$. Then we must have $(n+2)|5$.
But only $1$ and $5$ divide $5$. Thus, $n=3$, but that is not a solution since we assumed $n$ to be a perfect square. The problem therefore has no perfect-square solutions.

I'm not sure how relevant this is to the general case, but I did not manage to get any further.
Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Since this looks like a contest problem, could you tell us where it comes from?

Comment: I came across the problem secondhand, so I'd actually be grateful if someone could provide the source.

Comment: It may even help if you can state where this "secondhand" is. The most important thing is that it doesn't belong to an ongoing contest. Besides, the source of the problem may indicate the expected level of mathematics needed for solving it.

Comment: It's from APMO 2013/2. Several solutions exist online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $m^2=n-k$ be the largest square less than or equal to $n$.
$\implies0\le k\le 2m$

We have $n-k+2|n^2+1$
$$\implies n-k+2|1+n(k-2)$$
$$\implies n-k+2|k^2-4k+5$$
$$\implies m^2+2|k^2-4k+5$$
$\dfrac{k^2-4k+5}{m^2+2}=1,2\text{ or }3$ otherwise the inequality $0\le k\le 2m$ is violated.

---

If $\dfrac{k^2-4k+5}{m^2+2}=1$ we then have $(k-m-2)(k+m-2)=1$.
The only solutions for the above equality are $(m,k)=(0,1),(0,3)$, but $k>2m$, so no solution exists.

---

$\dfrac{k^2-4k+5}{m^2+2}=2$ we then have $(k-2)^2+1=2m^2+4$. $k$ should be odd. The LHS is of the form $8k+2$ while RHS is of the form $8k+4$ or $8k+6$. So no solution exists.

---

If $\dfrac{k^2-4k+5}{m^2+2}=3$ we then have $(k-2)^2+1=3m^2+6$. $3$ never divides the LHS so there are no  solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the source of the problem, I give here only a hint toward the solution.

---

Write $m = \lfloor n\rfloor$, so that $m^2 \leq n < (m + 1)^2$.

Write $n = m^2 + r$, so that $0\leq r \leq 2m$.

The condition then becomes $m^2 + 2 \mid (m^2 + r)^2 + 1$, which is equivalent to $m^2 + 2 \mid (r - 2)^2 + 1$.